# How to translate coordinates at loading GeoJSON objects for OpenLayers VectorlLayer?

Tags: typescript, openlayers, geojson

I have an image map with X Y coordinates and load Objects from GeoJSON source.
The coordinates in the JSON file need to be translated with a X and Y offset.
For this the geometry is taken and translated: `geometry.translate(162, 435)`, like in the below example. But instead of translating the coordinates of the object once, the translating (adding the offsets) loops infinitly till the object moves out of the map.

```js
objectsLayer = new VectorLayer({
    visible: true,
    source: new VectorSource({
      url: 'assets/objects.json',
      format: new GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: function (feature) {
      console.log('style: function');
      let geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      if (geometry instanceof Geometry) {
        geometry.translate(162, 435);
      }
      return new Style({
        image: new CircleStyle({
          radius: 5,
          stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'cyan', width: 1 }),
          fill: new Fill({ color: 'magenta' }),
        }),
      });
    },
  });
```

How to apply the translate function only once to each object?

Comment: Instead of  `let geometry = feature.getGeometry();` use `let geometry = feature.getGeometry().clone();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
objectsLayer = new VectorLayer({
    visible: true,
    source: new VectorSource({
      url: 'assets/objects.json',
      format: new GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: function (feature) {
      let geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      if (geometry instanceof Geometry) {
        geometry = geometry.clone();
        geometry.translate(162, 435);
      }
      return new Style({
        geometry: geometry,
        image: new CircleStyle({
          radius: 5,
          stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'cyan', width: 1 }),
          fill: new Fill({ color: 'magenta' }),
        }),
      });
    },
  });
```

or

```
objectsLayer = new VectorLayer({
    visible: true,
    source: new VectorSource({
      url: 'assets/objects.json',
      format: new GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: new Style({
      geometry: function (feature) {
        let geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        if (geometry instanceof Geometry) {
          geometry = geometry.clone();
          geometry.translate(162, 435);
        }
        return geometry;
      },
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'cyan', width: 1 }),
        fill: new Fill({ color: 'magenta' }),
      }),
    }),
  });
```

should work.

Comment: Both works. Position is correct now. Now I see something else. The decision, if the object is displayed is made of the original position. If the original position is outside the window, but the translated position is on the visible map, the object is not shown.

Comment: It should appear if it is within the layer's renderBuffer.  You could increase that in the VectorLayer options.